# What is wrong with 他把椅子站在上面?

Tags: grammar

> [image: a comic I'm describing in Chinese; in panel 3 a boy stands on a chair]

Yesterday I was practicing with an iTalki teacher, and in describing the above comic I said:

> 他把椅子站在上面。

I meant "he stood on the chair".  The tutor said that's not correct, and I should say

> 他站在椅子上面。

He wasn't able to give me a precise explanation on the spot, but I asked him if I could say words to the effect of

> 他把椅子拖进来，然后站在上面。

And he said that was okay.  (I'm not completely sure I remember it correctly.)

**Question**: What is wrong with 他把椅子站在上面?

(PS. This is not the same question as [Why is "他在椅子上坐" wrong?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/16434/8099;) here I use 把 grammar, while this similar question does not.)

Comment: Considering: 他把椅子拖进来，然后(他)站在(椅子)上面。

Comment: 说的人多了就正确了。说的人少了就错误了。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

把 is a disposive marker. It marks the object that's to be disposed of. You need a verb that can dispose of objects

Example:

把椅子燒掉 = take the chair and burn it (the verb 'burn' can dispose of the object 'chair') [O]

把椅子打碎 = take the chair and break it (the verb 'break' can dispose of the object 'chair')[O]

把椅子站 = take the chair and stand (the verb 'stand' can't dispose of the object 'chair')[X]

> 他把椅子站在上面 is ungrammatical

> 他把椅子放在上面 is grammatical because the verb 'put' can dispose of the object 'chair'

> 他把椅子(拉出來)站在上面 would be grammatical because the verb 'pull out' can dispose of the object 'chair'

Comment: This seems like pretty fundamental information about 把, it's a pity it's not widely shared with students. Just wondering, do you have a reference for this very helpful information?

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler [把](https://cantoneseplus.com/character/420)  [3] [國] [prep] used before a direct object and a verb to convey the sense of disposal

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the use of
把:

When you use 把 before a noun, the chair is standing 在上面.

So, he is not indicated to stand 在上面.

If you would like to indicate that he stands,  you should put the 站 after him (he).

Answer (score 2):

把 means to have something done or to let/make.

For example, 把手洗了 = 洗手, meaning to have your hands washed or to wash your hand.

Here 把椅子站在上面，it could only mean let/make the chair stand up there, instead of stand on the chair. The difference here is that stand is an intransitive verb, and the noun following it could only be a subject instead of an object while the verb wash is a transitive verb, and you could express it in both ways.

Answer (score 1):

x他把椅子站在上面

✔️他坐在椅子下面

✔️他站在椅子上面

✔️他把椅子放好,站在上面

.....

Answer (score 0):

What is the "problem" with using 把 in the context of the comic?

(A)  他站在椅子上面:-

他 --- He

站在 --- stood on

椅子上面 --- on the chair.

(B)  他把椅子站在上面:-

他 --- He

把 --- let / put

椅子 --- the chair

站在上面 --- (to) stand up there.

Explanation:-

Both sentences are grammatically correct following the "SVO" structure but differ radically in meaning, (though (B) is structurally awkward)

In 他站在椅子上面:-

他 --- He (Subject)

站在 --- stood on (Verb)

椅子上面 --- on the chair (Object)

In 他把椅子站在上面:-

他 --- He (Subject)

把椅子站在 --- let / put the chair (to) stand (Verb)

上面 --- up there (Object)

Therefore the semantic confusion revolves around exactly "who" or "what" is doing the "standing"; the "He" or the "Chair"?

Finally, with regards to 上面, there is a semantic shift between the two sentences. In (A), it means "on the", in (B), it means "up there"

Answer (score 0):

Let's make the lines of the story:

- 他想敲碎這面鏡子,可是這鏡子太高了,"所以他找了**ㄧ把**椅子站在上面...". The last phrase can also be constructed as "所以他站在**ㄧ把**找來的椅子上面...".

Note that both contain the expression in your thought - "he stood on the chair". And, in both, 把 is used as a "measure word(量词)", similar to "ㄧ張", "ㄧ個".....

Now, let's see what 把 means/does in the pattern of 他把...

- 他**把事情**搞砸了 = He failed **the thing**.
- 他**把我**搞糊塗了 = He confused **me**, or He **made me** confusing.
- 他**把椅子**放在鏡子前 = He placed **the chair** in front of the mirror, ...

In the examples above, 把 always associates with an action (搞 and 放 respectively) that causes/triggers an effect (砸了,糊塗了,在..前) on the object (事情,我,椅子) following it. The full sentence of the last example can be:

- 他**把椅子**放在鏡子前,然後站在**那把椅子**上面. This includes both the pattern "他把" and the measure word "那(一)把", as described in the beginning.

**What is wrong with 他把椅子站在上面?**

**Grammatically no mistake**, but it does not reflect the thought you wanted to express - "He stood on the chair". Instead, it vaguely says "He placed the chair on top" (on top of what?), which can be improved by adding an object after 在 - "他把椅子站在**桌子**上面", or adding an action - "他把椅子**放好**站在上面 (He stably placed the chair and stood on it).

Comment: how is the 量词 meaning of 把 related to the OP's question? why do not you also add the meaning of 把 (bà) in your comments as well? It makes no sense to just search the web/dict and list whatever you know/find out. Please answer to the point of the question.